# disable 8.3 name creation in web.config file

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

i use asp .net core version 3.1.
i know that for disabling 8.3 name creation i can set NtfsDisable8dot3NameCreation vaule to 1 on below path.

```
"HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControleSet\Control\FileSystem"
```

but my problem is that i dont know how i can set this configuration in web.config file.
actualy i want to use web.config XMl code for solving this issue.
and i try below setting in webconfig but get error when run project.

```
<configuration>
<HKLM>
    <SYSTEM>
        <CurrentControleSet>
            <Control>
                <FileSystem>
                    <add key="NtfsDisable8dot3NameCreation" value="1"/>
                </FileSystem>
            </Control>
        </CurrentControleSet>
    </SYSTEM>
</HKLM>
</configuration>
```

Comment: web.config is not a "thing" any more in .net core... not sure how to achieve this but i would not focus on web.config.... as web.config became more of an "internal" thing of .net core.

Comment: Hi jonathan,Are you sure about this?this is very important to me solving this problem via web.config @Jonathan Alfaro

Comment: You can of course use a web.config, if you deploy to IIS, but maybe try to explain which problem you are trying to solve and maybe we can find a better solution?

Comment: To be honest if I needed to manipulate the registry i would do it programmatically rather than in web.config. And yes I am sure web.config is not a thing in .net core. As a matter of fact I would discourage you from using web.config at all because it kind of defeats the purpose of .net core.

Comment: I have not had a web.config file in any of .net core projects since... probably ever

Comment: Tank's @Jonathan Alfaro